# .css() not changing until second click - using shared class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using a lightbox triggered by many elements. I need to alter the style (light to dark) when one unique element is clicked so I added an id to that element. I then force the css default on each click of lightbox but added an override on the #saved id. I am still learning jquery. Assuming I may need to unload that first click function.

What happens is that if #saved is clicked it is always ignored however it works fine the second time forward. Even clicking from .lightbox to #saved elements back and forth triggers properly. Addditionally if a .lightbox element is clicked first, then #saved - #saved lunches with the correct css. In conclusion the only time this fails on the first click is if #saved is the first element with a class of .lightbox that is clicked.

HTML:

```
Typical
<a href="/" class="lightbox">click me</a>

Unique
<a href="/" class="lightbox" id="saved">click me too</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var cssLB='.jquery-lightbox-mode-html .jquery-lightbox-background,.jquery-lightbox-loading,.jquery-lightbox-mode-html .jquery-lightbox-loading';

$('.lightbox').lightbox().click(function(){$(cssLB).css('background','#FFF url(/inc/img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;')});

$('#saved').click(function(){
  $(cssLB).css('background','#000 url(/inc/img/loading-dark.gif)');
});
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, add an alert() statement to your $("#saved").click() function. I want to see if that fires on your first click. I remember having this problem years ago and it had something to do with initilization but I can't remember right off hand. I'll dig in the site where I had the problem to see if I can figure it out. Post a response to see if the alert fires on the first click.

Comment: It is triggered upon first click however no css change until second click. I am having similar issues with solution below but still working on it.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're still getting this problem from Gaby's solution below?

Comment: yes. if you look at cssLB it is actually multiple classes stacked just as they are in the css file. There are 3 classes (note the commas). I think Gaby's solution may work if I add/remove once per each class

Comment: to clarify Gaby's answer does not change the class on click. no error, the lightbox still fires but no class change.

Comment: @user1101267 updated answer to accommodate overlapping properties..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid situations where you cannot determine the order the event handlers are called, you should do a single bind and identify the best route from there..

Also you should use classes instead of manually changing the CSS.

**CSS**

```
.typical{background: #FFF url(/inc/img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}
.unique{background: #000 url(/inc/img/loading-dark.gif);}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cssLB='.jquery-lightbox-mode-html .jquery-lightbox-background,.jquery-lightbox-loading,.jquery-lightbox-mode-html .jquery-lightbox-loading';

    $('.lightbox').lightbox().click(function(){
        if ( $(this).is('#saved') ){
            $(cssLB).removeClass('typical').addClass('unique');
        } else {
            $(cssLB).removeClass('unique').addClass('typical');
        }

    });
});
```

Additionally, if you have multiple elements that are `saved` then you should use a class instead of an id, as those should be unique..

---

**Update**

***A note*** : *the second class in your `cssLB` variable includes the third class. So you  might want to remove the 3rd one.. (for performance)*.

**CSS precedence** : If these classes have the `background` property defined, then you will have to [increase the specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) of the `typical` and `unique` classes or apply the [`!important` declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) to enforce them.

**Using `!important`**

```
.typical{background: #FFF url(/inc/img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center!important;}
.unique{background: #000 url(/inc/img/loading-dark.gif)!important;}
```

**Using increased specificity**

```
.jquery-lightbox-mode-html .jquery-lightbox-background .typical,
.jquery-lightbox-loading .typical,
.jquery-lightbox-mode-html .jquery-lightbox-loading .typical {
    background: #FFF url(/inc/img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
.jquery-lightbox-mode-html .jquery-lightbox-background .unique,
.jquery-lightbox-loading .unique,
.jquery-lightbox-mode-html .jquery-lightbox-loading .unique{
    background: #000 url(/inc/img/loading-dark.gif);
}
```